# How can I get Filename using Batch?

Tags: batch-file, filenames

This question is asked a number of times online, so I apologize in advance for asking, but unfortunately I can't get my code to run.

**Background Info:**

Each file has a prefix (or suffix) with the date -- thus the wildcards before and after the "RootFileName".

I feel like the code above should give me the file name (%~nF)... but as soon as my code hits the section below, it terminates the batch process.

**My Code:**

```
:fileprocessing
pause
FOR /R %F in ("K:\path\*RootFileName*.txt") DO (
    echo %~nF
    pause
    )
```

*Note:* Pauses were added above when troubleshooting to find exactly where my batch was terminating.

I have also tried:

```
:fileprocessing
pause
FOR /R "K:\path\" %F in (*RootFileName*.txt) DO (
    echo %~nF
    pause
    )
```

**My Issue:**

As soon as my batch hits the section of code above, it terminates (i.e. I never see my echo'd file name & the second 'Pause' step never triggers).

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Open a command prompt window, enter `for /?` or `help for` and execute with RETURN. Now you get displayed help of command __FOR__ which you should read carefully, best all pages, not just first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double <kbd>%</kbd> when referencing the metavariable `%F` in a batch file, hence

```
FOR /R "K:\path" %%F in (*RootFileName*.txt) DO (
    echo %%~nF
```

Comment: That stopped the termination issue.  Thank you!  However, now it is skipping the filename echo and advancing straight to the second pause?

Comment: It actually looks like it isn't running any of the DO() command and skipping to another troubleshooting pause I placed before my program exit.  Any suggestions as to why it is skipping the DO()?

Comment: Works perfectly well for me using `FOR /R "M:\seattle" %%F in (*d23*) DO (    echo %%~nF
    pause
    ) [newlines as you had them] - my system dutifully showed the filename and paused.

Comment: I was an idiot and still using my most recent version of the code (first set above). @zb226 helped me realize what I was doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Magoo's answer, it seems you need to use your second form:

```
:fileprocessing
pause
FOR /R "K:\path\" %%F IN (*RootFileName*.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%~nF
    pause
)
```